# what is the actual use of constructur in java

Tags: java, constructor

Constructor is just as like a method have the same name of class and is used to initialize the  objects ; it can be also be done through a method. Explain internally what happends when object is called?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the Use of Constructor in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056564/what-is-the-use-of-constructor-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method can only called through an instance unless it is `static`. Constructors are much better than calling a `static` method in the OO world.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors are used to do the initialization during creation. Other methods will do the initialization post construction. If an exception happens in a constructor , the object will not be created but not true in the other case.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is automatically called when the object is initialized-  when you create the object with new.  So you allocate and initialize the object in 1 step.  This can't be done with a normal function-  you'd need to do it in 2 steps without constructors

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is just as like a method(**without return type**) have the same name of class and is used to initialize the variables before object creation.

If you dont write constructor , compiler internally creates a default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

you can execute some basic code of the Constructors as soon as you create an object of constructor but its basic purpose is to do the initialization during creation of object.

Comment: We can also initialize objects through methods also,then what is the need of the constructur?

Comment: when u use a method, u need to call that method using the object.but what Constructors dose it initialize the variable as soon as object is created without calling the method . And these variable may be the required in other parts of the Constructors so u need to initialize it at starting only

Comment: @Rakesh but there will not be any difference if you  use the method and  call it to  initialize the variable before calling any other method of that class

Comment: @Rakesh using method 
step 1 u need to create objec of class
step 2 then call the method using object


using Constructor
only one step create an object..thats it

Answer (score 0):

Often times your classes will have some internal state. And you would like to ensure that the internal state is initialized before an instance of that class is used.

The fact that you can have a method in the class do the same job is true, however it will be a bad design in most cases and Object Oriented Programming in nothing but a design paradigm.

In yet other situations you would want to ensure some preconditions be met before an instance is created, this can also be captured by a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, objects must have some `default valid state` when created. For example, wrapper Integer class, any Integer object must have a valid int value when created. Constructors are a way of `injecting that valid state inside a newly created object`. Its a like a contract which JVM honors. When ever a new object is created:

- memory is allocated then
- Right constructor of that class is called.